# SQL Find duplicate with several field (no unique ID) WORK AROUND

Tags: sql, database, oracle, inner-join

I am trying to find duplicated vendors from a database using several fields from *vendor* table and *vendor_address* table.  The thing is the more inner join I make the less the query is loosing potential results. While I don't have duplicate in vendor ID I'm look to find potential one that are similar.

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT 
     o.vendor_id
    ,o.vndr_name_shrt_user
    ,O.COUNTRY 
    ,O.VENDOR_NAME_SHORT 
    ,B.POSTAL
    ,B.ADDRESS1
    ,SAME_ADDRESS_NB
    ,SAME_POSTAL_NB
    ,OC.SAME_SHORT_NAME
    ,oc.SAME_USER_NUM
FROM VENDOR o

JOIN vendor_addr B ON o.VENDOR_ID = B.VENDOR_ID

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT vndr_name_shrt_user, COUNT(*) AS SAME_USER_NUM
    FROM VENDOR 
    WHERE COUNTRY = 'CANADA'
    AND VENDOR_STATUS = 'A'
    GROUP BY vndr_name_shrt_user
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) oc on o.vndr_name_shrt_user = oc.vndr_name_shrt_user

INNER JOIN ( SELECT VENDOR_NAME_SHORT, COUNT(*) AS SAME_SHORT_NAME
    FROM VENDOR 
    WHERE COUNTRY = 'CANADA'
    AND VENDOR_STATUS = 'A'
    GROUP BY VENDOR_NAME_SHORT
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) oc on o.VENDOR_NAME_SHORT = oc.VENDOR_NAME_SHORT

INNER JOIN (SELECT POSTAL, COUNT(*) AS SAME_POSTAL_NB
    FROM vendor_addr 
    WHERE COUNTRY = 'CANADA'
    AND COUNTRY ='CANADA'
    AND POSTAL != ' '
    GROUP BY POSTAL
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) oc on b.POSTAL = oc.POSTAL

INNER JOIN (SELECT ADDRESS1, COUNT(*) AS SAME_ADDRESS_NB
    FROM ps_vendor_addr 
    WHERE COUNTRY = 'CANADA'
    AND COUNTRY ='CANADA'
    AND ADDRESS1 != ' '
    GROUP BY ADDRESS1
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) oc on b.ADDRESS1 = oc.ADDRESS1   
WHERE O.COUNTRY ='CANADA' 
    AND B.COUNTY = 'CANADA';
```

Comment: Why are you Inner joining? Use a left outer join for the places you don't want to lose data.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including the DDL statement for your table and DML statements for some example data and your expected output for that data.

Comment: Thank you sir well tough

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if your joins are a bit interesting, for more reasons than one. Firstly, you have inner joins, which will eliminate all but those which have *all* signs of duplications - this is something which you don't want. Additionally, you seem to have the same alias, oc, on all derived tables - that's not really gonna fly here, and you're not going to get very far with that.

Instead of doing it this way, I'd suggest that you have your basic query repeated for each of the duplication signs - as follows (I removed the same_address_nb and same_postal_nb fields, and you'll see why):

```
select 
    o.vendor_id
    ,o.vndr_name_shrt_user
    ,O.COUNTRY 
    ,O.VENDOR_NAME_SHORT 
    ,B.POSTAL
    ,B.ADDRESS1
    ,OC.SAME_SHORT_NAME
    ,oc.SAME_USER_NUM
from VENDOR o
JOIN vendor_addr B ON o.VENDOR_ID = B.VENDOR_ID
WHERE O.COUNTRY ='CANADA'
AND B.COUNTY = 'CANADA'
AND ...
```

For each one of these duplication signs, you'll add a nested query to the ellipses shown above as follows - example shown using the duplicate in vndr_name_shrt_user:

```
select 
    o.vendor_id
    ,o.vndr_name_shrt_user
    ,O.COUNTRY 
    ,O.VENDOR_NAME_SHORT 
    ,B.POSTAL
    ,B.ADDRESS1
    ,OC.SAME_SHORT_NAME
    ,oc.SAME_USER_NUM
    ,'SAME_USER_NUM' as duplicateFlag
from VENDOR o
JOIN vendor_addr B ON o.VENDOR_ID = B.VENDOR_ID
WHERE O.COUNTRY ='CANADA'
AND B.COUNTY = 'CANADA'
AND o.vndr_name_shrt_user in 
(
    SELECT 
        vndr_name_shrt_user
    FROM VENDOR 
    WHERE COUNTRY = o.country
    AND VENDOR_STATUS = 'A'
    GROUP BY vndr_name_shrt_user
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

You can `UNION ALL` these queries together and then see all of your duplicates.

As a side note, you had a check for the `country = 'canada'` twice in the last three derived table.

**UPDATE**: showing more than one duplicate flag

```
select 
    o.vendor_id
    ,o.vndr_name_shrt_user
    ,O.COUNTRY 
    ,O.VENDOR_NAME_SHORT 
    ,B.POSTAL
    ,B.ADDRESS1
    ,OC.SAME_SHORT_NAME
    ,oc.SAME_USER_NUM
    ,'SAME_USER_NUM' as duplicateFlag
from VENDOR o
JOIN vendor_addr B ON o.VENDOR_ID = B.VENDOR_ID
WHERE O.COUNTRY ='CANADA'
AND B.COUNTY = 'CANADA'
AND o.vndr_name_shrt_user in 
(
    SELECT 
        vndr_name_shrt_user
    FROM VENDOR 
    WHERE COUNTRY = o.country
    AND VENDOR_STATUS = 'A'
    GROUP BY vndr_name_shrt_user
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) 

UNION ALL

select 
    o.vendor_id
    ,o.vndr_name_shrt_user
    ,O.COUNTRY 
    ,O.VENDOR_NAME_SHORT 
    ,B.POSTAL
    ,B.ADDRESS1
    ,OC.SAME_SHORT_NAME
    ,oc.SAME_USER_NUM
    ,'VENDOR_NAME_SHORT' as duplicateFlag
from VENDOR o
JOIN vendor_addr B ON o.VENDOR_ID = B.VENDOR_ID
WHERE O.COUNTRY ='CANADA'
AND B.COUNTY = 'CANADA'
AND o.VENDOR_NAME_SHORT in 
(
    SELECT 
        VENDOR_NAME_SHORT
    FROM VENDOR 
    WHERE COUNTRY = o.country
    AND VENDOR_STATUS = 'A'
    GROUP BY VENDOR_NAME_SHORT
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: Having only one duplicated flag make the query full on of dupicated flag isnt it or I create 'SAME_USER_NUM' as duplicateFlag2 ?

Comment: You would put the different duplicate flags as the last column - I'll update the query with an example

Comment: Should I remove 
OC.SAME_SHORT_NAME,
oc.SAME_USER_NUM

as I created them in the original query + I get too many results as error

thanks alot btw

Comment: Yes, I would remove those fields as well - since you will now have the ID of the vendors who are potential duplicates, and on which field they are suspect of being a duplicate. How are you sure that you're getting false positives on this list?

Comment: I'm reading on false positive atm sorry 

I still get the error too many line for the nested select and union all

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message (copy/paste)?

Comment: ORA-00913: trop de valeurs
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Erreur à la ligne 45, colonne 5

Comment: After adding the second select (after UNION ALL)

Comment: LINE 45 IS THE BEGINIG OF AND o.VENDOR_NAME_SHORT in 
(
    SELECT 
        VENDOR_NAME_SHORT, COUNT(*) AS 
    FROM VENDOR 
    WHERE COUNTRY = o.country
    AND VENDOR_STATUS = 'A'
    GROUP BY VENDOR_NAME_SHORT
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)

Comment: Ok, I just fixed that one - see the updated post. The nested query cannot have more than one column - I had left the `count(*)` which you had initially put in there. It's out now and should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Lets have some interesting data with chained duplicates on different attributes:

```
CREATE TABLE data ( ID, A, B, C ) AS
  SELECT 1, 1, 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Related to #2 on column A
  SELECT 2, 1, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Related to #1 on column A, #3 on B & C, #5 on C
  SELECT 3, 2, 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Related to #2 on columns B & C, #5 on C
  SELECT 4, 3, 3, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Related to #5 on column A
  SELECT 5, 3, 4, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Related to #2 and #3 on column C, #4 on A
  SELECT 6, 5, 5, 5 FROM DUAL;          -- Unrelated
```

Now, we can get some relationships using analytic functions (without any joins):

```
SELECT d.*,
       LEAST(
         FIRST_VALUE( id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY a ORDER BY id ),
         FIRST_VALUE( id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY b ORDER BY id ),
         FIRST_VALUE( id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY c ORDER BY id )
       ) AS duplicate_of
FROM   data d;
```

Which gives:

```
ID A B C DUPLICATE_OF
-- - - - ------------
 1 1 1 1            1
 2 1 2 2            1
 3 2 2 2            2
 4 3 3 3            4
 5 3 4 2            2
 6 5 5 5            6
```

But that doesn't pick up that #4 is related to #5 which is related to #2 and then to #1...

This can be found with a hierarchical query:

```
SELECT id, a, b, c,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT( id ) AS duplicate_of
FROM   data
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE ( PRIOR a = a OR PRIOR b = b OR PRIOR c = c );
```

But that will give many, many duplicate rows (since it does not know where to start the hierarchy from so will chose each row in turn as the root) - instead you can use the first query to give the hierarchical query a starting point when the `ID` and `DUPLICATE_OF` values are the same:

```
SELECT id, a, b, c,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT( id ) AS duplicate_of
FROM   (
  SELECT d.*,
         LEAST(
           FIRST_VALUE( id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY a ORDER BY id ),
           FIRST_VALUE( id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY b ORDER BY id ),
           FIRST_VALUE( id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY c ORDER BY id )
         ) AS duplicate_of
  FROM   data d
)
START WITH id = duplicate_of
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE ( PRIOR a = a OR PRIOR b = b OR PRIOR c = c );
```

Which gives:

```
ID A B C DUPLICATE_OF
-- - - - ------------
 1 1 1 1            1
 2 1 2 2            1
 3 2 2 2            1
 4 3 3 3            1
 5 3 4 2            1
 1 1 1 1            4
 2 1 2 2            4
 3 2 2 2            4
 4 3 3 3            4
 5 3 4 2            4
 6 5 5 5            6
```

There are still some rows are duplicated because of the local minima in the search that occurs a #4 ... which can be removed with a simple `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT id, a, b, c,
       MIN( duplicate_of ) AS duplicate_of
FROM   (
  SELECT id, a, b, c,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT( id ) AS duplicate_of
  FROM   (
    SELECT d.*,
           LEAST(
             FIRST_VALUE( id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY a ORDER BY id ),
             FIRST_VALUE( id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY b ORDER BY id ),
             FIRST_VALUE( id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY c ORDER BY id )
           ) AS duplicate_of
    FROM   data d
  )
  START WITH id = duplicate_of
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE ( PRIOR a = a OR PRIOR b = b OR PRIOR c = c )
)
GROUP BY id, a, b, c;
```

Which gives the output:

```
ID A B C DUPLICATE_OF
-- - - - ------------
 1 1 1 1            1
 2 1 2 2            1
 3 2 2 2            1
 4 3 3 3            1
 5 3 4 2            1
 6 5 5 5            6
```

Comment: process take alot of time

Comment: SELECT vendor_id, VENDOR_NAME_SHORT, VNDR_NAME_SHRT_USR, NAME1,
       MIN( duplicate_of ) AS duplicate_of
FROM   (
  SELECT vendor_id, VENDOR_NAME_SHORT, VNDR_NAME_SHRT_USR, NAME1,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT( vendor_id ) AS duplicate_of
  FROM   (
    SELECT D.*,

Comment: LEAST(
             FIRST_VALUE( vendor_id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY VENDOR_NAME_SHORT ORDER BY vendor_id ),
             FIRST_VALUE( vendor_id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY VNDR_NAME_SHRT_USR ORDER BY vendor_id ),
             FIRST_VALUE( vendor_id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY NAME1 ORDER BY vendor_id )
           ) AS duplicate_of
    FROM   PS_VENDOR d
  )
  START WITH vendor_id = duplicate_of
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE ( PRIOR VENDOR_NAME_SHORT = VENDOR_NAME_SHORT OR PRIOR VNDR_NAME_SHRT_USR = VNDR_NAME_SHRT_USR OR PRIOR NAME1 = NAME1 )
)
GROUP BY vendor_id, VENDOR_NAME_SHORT, VNDR_NAME_SHRT_USR, NAME1