# SQL ORACLE - get group of IDs between has path

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like this:

```
ID1 | ID2
==========
A   | B
C   | B
A   | F
G   | B
G   | E
J   | B
X   | Y
Z   | Y
```

I have to write SQL SELECT that find(marks) separate groups. In this example I have two groups: A,B,C,F,G,E,J and X,Y,Z. It is like all that have path(without direction) between them(like Family relation).There is no matter it will be string(with **LISTAGG** or with path (**CONNECT BY** or **CYCLE**) for example) or new column with group identifiers like

```
ID1 | ID2 | GROUP
=================
A   | B   | 1
C   | B   | 1
A   | F   | 1
G   | B   | 1
G   | E   | 1
J   | B   | 1
X   | Y   | 2
Z   | Y   | 2
```

If there is one more row with [A,Z] then all distinct letters are one group.
I think its have to something with **CONNECT BY** or **CYCLE** but I don't know how it have to looks like.

Comment: If the first two rows were "X | Y " and "Z | Y" - does that make them group 1? Also, to make things clear, if the value in column ID1 is encountered more than one time OR if the value in column ID2 is encountered more than one time - that's your grouping condition - correct? If the last statement is correct, what's the ordering ; as I mentioned, what if the last two rows were returned first, does that make them group 1?

Comment: ORDERing there is no matter. "X | Y " can be first and "Z | Y" be last and that is one group (numering of groups is sample and we can have 1,1,2,1,3 as values in column GROUP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45864596/1509264):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e469c/13)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ids ( ID1, ID2 ) AS
  SELECT 'A', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'G', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'G', 'E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'J', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'X', 'Y' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Z', 'Y' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH indexed_ids ( id, id1, id2 ) AS (
  SELECT ROWNUM, id1, id2 FROM ids
),
grouped_ids ( id, id1, id2, min_id ) AS (
  SELECT i.*,
         LEAST(
           MIN( id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id1 ),
           MIN( id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id2 )
         ) AS min_id
  FROM   indexed_ids i
)
SELECT id, id1, id2,
       MIN( "GROUP" ) AS "GROUP"
FROM   (
  SELECT id, id1, id2,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT( id ) AS "GROUP"
  FROM   grouped_ids g
  START WITH id = min_id
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE ( PRIOR id1 IN ( id1, id2 ) OR PRIOR id2 IN ( id1, id2 ) )
)
GROUP BY id, id1, id2
ORDER BY id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e469c/13/0)**:

```
| ID | ID1 | ID2 | GROUP |
|----|-----|-----|-------|
|  1 |   A |   B |     1 |
|  2 |   C |   B |     1 |
|  3 |   A |   F |     1 |
|  4 |   G |   B |     1 |
|  5 |   G |   E |     1 |
|  6 |   J |   B |     1 |
|  7 |   X |   Y |     7 |
|  8 |   Z |   Y |     7 |
```

The `GROUP` column identifies the minimum `ID` of the group. If you want a sequential `GROUP` then you can use the `DENSE_RANK()` analytic function.

Answer (score 1):

I think You could use `connect_by_root` here:

```
select id1, listagg(root) within group (order by root) list
  from (select distinct id1, root
          from (select t.*, connect_by_root(id1) root
                  from (select id1, id2 from t union select id2, id1 from t) t
                  connect by nocycle prior id1 = id2))
  group by id1
```

... gives us:

```
A   ABCEFGJ
B   ABCEFGJ
C   ABCEFGJ
E   ABCEFGJ
F   ABCEFGJ
G   ABCEFGJ
J   ABCEFGJ
X   XYZ
Y   XYZ
Z   XYZ
```

Rest is simple, use `dense_rank()` and join with original table:

```
with t(id1, id2) as (
    select 'A', 'B' from dual union all
    select 'C', 'B' from dual union all
    select 'A', 'F' from dual union all
    select 'G', 'B' from dual union all
    select 'G', 'E' from dual union all
    select 'J', 'B' from dual union all
    select 'X', 'Y' from dual union all
    select 'Z', 'Y' from dual),
q as (
    select id1, listagg(root) within group (order by root) list
      from (select distinct id1, root
              from (select t.*, connect_by_root(id1) root
                      from (select id1, id2 from t union select id2, id1 from t) t
                      connect by nocycle prior id1 = id2))
      group by id1)
select id1, id2, dense_rank() over (order by list) grp
  from t join q using (id1)
```

Result:

```
ID1 ID2        GRP
--- --- ----------
A   F            1
A   B            1
C   B            1
G   E            1
J   B            1
G   B            1
X   Y            2
Z   Y            2
8 rows selected
```