# Group a set of nodes in SQL so that there is no link between the groups

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping

I have an SQL query that gets a list of projects. The problem is that a project can be linked to another project (because it shares some resource). I would like to obtain groups of projects such that no resources are shared between the groups.

I am sure that it is a common graph problem but I don't know how to approach it. What is the best way to approach the problem and is there an algorithm to solve it in an SQL query?

(Edit) Trying with a hierarchical approach is slow on the data I have, I guess because it is not organised in a hierarchy. It could be pre-processed to make it more hierarchical:

```
          (1)           (1)             (1)
          /|\     =>     |          =>   |
        /  | \          (3) .. (4)      (3) .. (4)
      (3)..|..(4)         \                     |
          (5)             (5)                  (5)
```

I see a way to do this but not how to know when to stop the process, other than counting all the changes in each iteration and stopping when no changes are possible. Is a recursive way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PL/SQL Solution based on performing a Depth-First Search:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2876de/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE projects ( project ) AS
  SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
/

CREATE TABLE project_links ( project, link ) AS
  SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 6 FROM DUAL
/

CREATE TYPE IntList IS TABLE OF INTEGER
/

CREATE TYPE project_group IS OBJECT(
  project       INTEGER,
  project_group INTEGER
)
/

CREATE TYPE project_group_tab IS TABLE OF PROJECT_GROUP
/

CREATE PACKAGE projects_pkg IS
  TYPE project_vertex
    IS RECORD(
      project       PROJECTS.PROJECT%TYPE,
      project_group INTEGER,
      links         IntList
    );

  TYPE project_vertex_assoc_array
    IS TABLE OF project_vertex
    INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

  FUNCTION get_project_groups RETURN project_group_tab PIPELINED;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY projects_pkg IS
  FUNCTION get_project_groups RETURN project_group_tab PIPELINED
  IS
    p_projects project_vertex_assoc_array;
    i          PLS_INTEGER;
    j          PLS_INTEGER;
    k          PLS_INTEGER;
    g          PLS_INTEGER := 0;
    stack      IntList;

  BEGIN
    FOR rec IN ( SELECT project FROM projects )
    LOOP
      p_projects(rec.project).project := rec.project;
      p_projects(rec.project).links   := IntList();
    END LOOP;

    FOR rec IN ( SELECT project, link FROM project_links )
    LOOP
      p_projects(rec.project).links.EXTEND;
      p_projects(rec.project).links(p_projects(rec.project).links.COUNT) := rec.link;
      p_projects(rec.link).links.EXTEND;
      p_projects(rec.link).links(p_projects(rec.link).links.COUNT) := rec.project;
    END LOOP;

    i := p_projects.FIRST;
    WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
      IF p_projects(i).project_group IS NULL THEN
        g := g + 1;
        stack := IntList( i );
        p_projects(i).project_group := g;
        WHILE stack.COUNT > 0 LOOP
          j := stack(stack.COUNT);
          stack.TRIM;
          FOR n IN REVERSE 1 .. p_projects(j).links.COUNT LOOP
            k := p_projects(j).links(n);
            IF p_projects(k).project_group IS NULL THEN
              p_projects(k).project_group := g;
              stack.EXTEND;
              stack( stack.COUNT ) := k;
            END IF;
          END LOOP;
        END LOOP;
      END IF;
      PIPE ROW(
        project_group(
          p_projects(i).project,
          p_projects(i).project_group
        )
      );
      i := p_projects.NEXT(i);
    END LOOP;
  END;
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE( projects_pkg.get_project_groups )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2876de/1/0)**:

```
| PROJECT | PROJECT_GROUP |
|---------|---------------|
|       1 |             1 |
|       2 |             1 |
|       3 |             1 |
|       4 |             1 |
|       5 |             1 |
|       6 |             2 |
|       7 |             2 |
|       8 |             2 |
|       9 |             2 |
|      10 |             3 |
```

Comment: Ok, so PL/SQL is the way to go. Thanks :)

Comment: `p_projects(rec.project).links.EXTEND;` Is it really needed, You already declared it as associative array.

Comment: @XING `p_projects` is an associative array, `p_projects(n).links` is a collection so, yes, it does need to be extended.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve it is to use a hierarchical query:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f514/10)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE projects ( project ) AS
  SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;

CREATE TABLE project_links ( project, link ) AS
  SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 6 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH two_way_links AS (
  SELECT project, link
  FROM   project_links
  UNION ALL
  SELECT link, project
  FROM   project_links
  GROUP BY project, link
)
SELECT MIN( CONNECT_BY_ROOT( p.project ) ) As root,
       COALESCE( l.link, p.project ) AS projects
FROM   projects p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN two_way_links l
       ON ( p.project = l.project )
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR l.link = p.project
GROUP BY COALESCE( l.link, p.project )
ORDER  BY 1, 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f514/10/0)**:

```
| ROOT | PROJECTS |
|------|----------|
|    1 |        1 |
|    1 |        2 |
|    1 |        3 |
|    1 |        4 |
|    1 |        5 |
|    6 |        6 |
|    6 |        7 |
|    6 |        8 |
|    6 |        9 |
|   10 |       10 |
```

**Update**:

You can try speeding it up by attempting to find the minimum group value:

[(Explanation here in a related question)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45864596/1509264)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f514/13)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE projects ( project ) AS
  SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;

CREATE TABLE project_links ( project, link ) AS
  SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 6 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH two_way_links AS (
  SELECT project, link
  FROM   project_links
  UNION ALL
  SELECT link, project
  FROM   project_links
  GROUP BY project, link
),
min_links AS (
  SELECT l.*,
         FIRST_VALUE( LEAST( project, link ) )
           OVER( PARTITION BY project ORDER BY link ) AS min_link
  FROM   two_way_links l
)
SELECT MIN( CONNECT_BY_ROOT( p.project ) ) As root,
       COALESCE( l.link, p.project ) AS projects
FROM   projects p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN min_links l
       ON ( p.project = l.project )
START WITH p.project = l.min_link OR l.min_link IS NULL
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR l.link = p.project
GROUP BY COALESCE( l.link, p.project )
ORDER  BY 1, 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f514/13/0)**:

```
| ROOT | PROJECTS |
|------|----------|
|    1 |        1 |
|    1 |        2 |
|    1 |        3 |
|    1 |        4 |
|    1 |        5 |
|    6 |        6 |
|    6 |        7 |
|    6 |        8 |
|    6 |        9 |
|   10 |       10 |
```

Comment: So for each project this gets all the paths that include it, and finds one that starts earliest. What about efficiency? I have about 6,000 projects and 8,000 two-way links between them, and the query hasn't terminated after 5 minutes

Comment: @TomSW It finds the one with the lowest value in the `project` column - if that corresponds to the one that start earliest then, yes.

Comment: @TomSW Updated with a (hopefully) faster version that does some calculations to determine a more restrictive set of rows to start the hierarchical part of the query from.

Comment: unfortunately no joy. I think using two-way links is dangerous, but using one-way links is not reliable, if a "child" node has several parents.